# Matching a text having line breaks with another String

Tags: javascript, testing, string-comparison

I am trying to get text from a popup message and then compare it with another string to check whether or not both are same.

### Pop-up Screen

[image]

### Testing Code

```
var text = element(by.css('.modal.fade.AppLockPopup.in'));
//expect(text.getText()).toEqual("Warning" + "\n" + " You haven't saved your changes.Are "+ "\n" +" you sure you want to discard your changes? "+ "\n" +" Yes No");
expect(text.getText()).toEqual("Warning You haven't saved your changes.Are you sure you want to discard your changes? Yes No");
```

### Current Output (Fails)

[image]

How do I compare these strings?

Comment: you are using some kind of js frameworks, add it as relative tag

Comment: === use this operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are having issues with spaces and newlines, I would suggest using a regular expression to normalize all sequences of whitespace into a single regular space before comparing the two values using your testing framework:

```js
var text = element(by.css('.modal.fade.AppLockPopup.in')).getText().then(function (e) {
  return e.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
})

expect(text).toEqual(
  "Warning You haven't saved your changes. Are you sure you want to discard your changes? Yes No"
)
```

Comment: it says .replace is not a function

Comment: I didn't realize `getText` returned a Promise. Let me edit my answer, one moment...